# Torch tensor equivalent function to matlab's "find"?

Tags: lua, torch

In a nutshell, I would like to know if there is a tensor command in torch that gives me the indices of elements in a tensor that satisfy a certain criteria.

Here is matlab code that illustrates what I would like to be able to do in torch:

```
my_mat = magic(3); % returns a 3 by 3 matrix with the numbers 1 through 9
greater_than_fives = find(my_mat > 5); % find indices of all values greater than 5, the " > 5" is a logical elementwise operator that returns a matrix of all 0's and 1's and finally the "find" command picks out the indices with a "1" in them
my_mat(greater_than_fives) = 0;  % set all values greater than 5 equal to 0
```

I understand that I could do this in torch using a for loop, but is there some equivalent to matlab's find command that would allow me to do this more compactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
x[x:gt(5)] = 0
```

In general there are x:gt :lt :ge :le :eq

There is also the general :apply function tha takes in an anonymous function and applies it to each element.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I was interested in both how to use the indices to index into my array (which is what you provided) but also how to find the indices themselves (which are frequently useful for other things beyond indexing into the original Tensor.

Comment: finding the indices themselves can be done via a very ugly hack:

indices = torch.linspace(1, x:nElement(), x:nElement())[x:gt(5)]

Comment: Boolean indexing does not seem to work for slicing only one tensor dimension. So, having a counterpart for find() / np.where() would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that `torch.linspace(1,x:nElement(), x:nElement())` doesn't always give you the numbers 1 to x:nElement() which I've just learned the hard way.  Instead `torch.range(1,x:nElement())` is the better way to do this.