# Torch tensor set the negative numbers to zero

Tags: lua, torch

`x=torch.Tensor({1,-1,3,-8})`

How to convert `x` such that all the negative values in x are replaced with zero without using a loop such that the tensor must look like

`th>x
1
0
3
0`

Comment: why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: I am using the code on GPU and will take a lot of time if i use a loop

Comment: `x[x:lt(0)] = 0` found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288203/torch-tensor-equivalent-function-to-matlabs-find

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pytorch supports indexing by operators

```
a = torch.Tensor([1,0,-1])
a[a < 0] = 0
a
```

tensor([1., 0., 0.])

Answer (score 6):

Actually, this operation is equivalent to applying [`ReLU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#relu) non-linear activation.

Just do this and you're good to go

```
output = torch.nn.functional.relu(a)
```

You can also do it in-place for faster computations:

```
torch.nn.functional.relu(a, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Pytorch takes care of broadcasting here :

```
x = torch.max(x,torch.tensor([0.]))
```